# style changes when zooming

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm developing a website. Everything looks great on 100% zoom but when I'm zooming in or out in chrome and IE (not Firefox) the style changes and div blocks move! I have a container div with a background and some div blocks on it. Everything should be in exact position and it is important in my site.

You can see in picture how it makes my style look so bad.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I tried to use percentage instead of pixel for sizing and positioning of all elements in the page but its not working.

My CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 880px;
    background-image: url('b80.png');
}
.picture{
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top:11px;
}
```

Comment: to be honest I never understood the problem. zooming in and out is not something "regular" users do. Have you ever seen your dad/mom/sis zoom in on a website? And its not even bad in your case. just a few pixels

Comment: DiederikEEn, my dad does indeed zoom, as do many older users and those with eyesight challenges. It's a valid concern. That said, pixel-perfect structures like in the image above may not work out that well. Alireza, show some code and explain what you're trying to accomplish. There may be better solutions.

Comment: "when I'm zooming in or out in chrome and IE (not in Firefox)the style changes and div blocks move!" Welcome to web design. It's not print; it's a fluid medium, where users can zoom (whole page or text only), can change their default font sizes, view on devices of all sizes etc. You have to design in such a way that elements reflow appropriately in all these circumstances.

Comment: @Mooseman I added Css code. I use margin for picture element to set it in right place where hexagon fit exactly. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Alireza you should try relative positioning in your css.

Comment: @Alireza Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem, when I tested in a different screen size.

Try `position: relative` or `display: inline-block` for `.picture`.  This may solve the issue.

Comment: @Alireza better make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we can have a visual and try to fix it.